# Error occurs when clicking after confirming using pyautogui

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyautogui

I use Python2.7, Win7 32bit.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.confirm(text=u'XXXX', title=r'XX', buttons=['OK', 'Cancel'])
pyautogui.click()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VisualNovelForScroll.py", line 28, in <module>
    pyautogui.click()
  File "F:/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 362, in click
    platformModule._click(x, y, 'left')
  File "F:/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 437, in _click
    _sendMouseEvent(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTCLICK, x, y)
  File "F:/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 480, in _sendMouseEvent
    raise ctypes.WinError()
WindowsError: [Error 1400] 无效的窗口句柄。
```

My Windows language is Chinese. 无效的窗口句柄 means `invalid windows handle`

I try to get the mouse position and send it as arguments into `pyautogui.click()`
However I get the same error.`

```
pyautogui.confirm(text=u'XXXX', title=r'XX', buttons=['OK', 'Cancel'])
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.click(currentMouseX, currentMouseY)
```

another failed attempt:

```
pyautogui.confirm(text=u'XXXX', title=r'XX', buttons=['OK', 'Cancel'])
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.moveTo(currentMouseX, currentMouseY)
pyautogui.click()
```

Thanks in advance. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error and found that it still performs the click- try this:

```
try:
    pyautogui.click()
except:
    print "Error-carrying on anyway"
```

Or if you don't want it to print anything:

```
try:
    pyautogui.click()
except:
    pass
```